# What are the steps to install Lucene on mac?

Tags: lucene

I am trying to learn Lucene step by step. However, I dont find a clear tutorial on line about how to install Lucene on Mac. Anyone knows? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For Lucene, I don't think you "install" it. Instead, it comes in a JAR file, which you include in the classpath of your application. Or, are you trying to setup Solr instead?

Comment: @KaiChan thanks for the help. I am now only trying to setup Lucene on my Macbook to learn how it works. Solr may be the next step. 

It seems that there are two types of the JAR files, one contains source code and the another has compiled binaries. So, I am not sure where I should get start. What's your suggestion on this? I wish I could compile the stuff and then port in some demos from another JAR to see how things work. But I dont know how to compile it yet....If you are able to help me a bit, that will be great! :)

Comment: Typically you only need the binary JAR file. It might be a good idea to use a Java-aware IDE like Eclipse (which compiles your Java code for you). Start a project and tell it to add the Lucene JAR file to its build path, and you can start writing your example program. Have you tried some of the Lucene tutorials like [this one](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)?

Comment: @KaiChan thanks A LOT for pointing me to the right direction! I have Eclipse installed and let me try if I can set everything up this afternoon :)

Comment: @KaiChan, can you please copy your last suggestions so that i can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new folder named lib in your project folder. This stands for "libraries" and will contain all the JARs you'll be using for that project.Copy the JARs you need to lib.
2. Expand lib in Eclipse and select all the JARs you need.
3. Right-click the JARs and navigate to Build Path.
4. Select Add to Build Path. The JARs will disappear from lib and reappear in Referenced Libraries.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! I've figured out how to do this with Kai's help. The steps are very clear, so i change to mark this as an answer for other's future reference.

Answer (score 3):

(copied from my comments above)

For Lucene, I don't think you "install" it. Instead, it comes in a JAR file, which you include in the classpath of your application. Typically you only need the binary JAR file. It might be a good idea to use a Java-aware IDE like Eclipse (which compiles your Java code for you). Start a project and tell it to add the Lucene JAR file to its build path, and you can start writing your example program. Have you tried some of the Lucene tutorials like [this one](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and easiest way I found to install lucene is to use Homebrew. Just do `brew install couchdb-lucene`. Now your `lucene-home` will be something like `\usr/local/Cellar/couchdb-lucene/2.0.0/libexec/`. For more info check [here](http://brewformulas.org/Couchdb-lucene). However, what I have notice, at the time of this writing, is that couchDB 1.6.1 (a dependency) will be installed instead of couchDB2 (if that is the version of couchDB you would like to use). From [couchdb documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/install/mac.html#installation-with-homebrew),"The Homebrew build of CouchDB 2.x is still in development."